# Ajax File/Image upload with tastypie, backbone, and knockout?

Tags: ajax, django, backbone.js, knockout.js, tastypie

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do a file/image upload with tastypie, backbone, and knockout

[knockout] I'm not sure what the data-bind is on the input so that I can upload a file:

```
// what I have right now
<input type="file" data-bind="value: image"/>
```

[backbone] I have the post url set but given the above setup, my file is only a string

```
imageModel.get("image") //gives me a string like C:/image
```

[tastypie] When the above model is saved, no file is uploaded, and the FileField is simply a string.  It doesn't even go through the normal upload_to=... django dynamics

```
# in my tastypie resource

class ImageResource(ModelResource):

    image = fields.FileField(attribute="image")
    # ...
```

I know this question has a lot of parts, so I would be really amazed if one solution addressed all of them. But can anyone point me in the right direction, especially the backbone to tastypie (only sending text) and the tastypie to db (not using upload_to and no file is saved) issues?

Answer (score 0):

The value binding will only give you the filename in text, if you need the actual file object you need a custom binding, I did one for my project and then used the FileReader html5 objec to stream the file to the server

```
ko.bindingHandlers.file = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            writeValueToProperty(valueAccessor(), allBindingsAccessor, "file", element.files[0]);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) == null) {
            element.value = "";
        }
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b85YC/